# django SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0

Tags: mysql, django, null

Using Mysql,  django-debug-toolbar, I see these useless(?) queries:

```
SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
Duplicated 2 times. 

SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
Duplicated 2 times.
```

This query is repeated 4 times. I couldn't find enough info on that.
How to remove it?
Why it is repeated?

Comment: See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24675 - it looks like this was fixed, maybe you need to update Django.

Comment: I saw that ticket. And it is still happens. I use django 1.9.

Comment: And what this query does anyway?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: The ticket has a link to the MySQL documentation of the variable. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_auto_is_null

Comment: According to the ticket, it only skips this in MySQL 5.6 and higher.

Comment: Never mind. The last comment says that it's not in any production version, it will be in Django1.10.

Comment: mysql 5.6.20, according to `SHOW VARIABLES;` version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24675#comment:18) this will be fixed in Django 1.10, which isn't yet released.

Comment: I use Django 2 and still, I can see the request.

Comment: @NikosKeyz Are you using MySQL 5.6.20 or newer? Anyway, I just reported what the ticket said, I can't be responsible if it's incorrect. Take it up with the Django developers.